# Can a function be discontinuous outside its domain of definition?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define a function $f$ by:

$f(x)=\ln(x), x>0$

It says that $0$ is a point of (infinite) discontinuity of $f$. But $0$ doesn't even belong to the domain of definition of $f$!

Comment: That's like asking "can you go to jail after your death".

Comment: It is technically incorrect, but the book (?) is presumably just saying that the function cannot be extended to be continuous at 0. It's not possible to give a better answer without more context.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common [abuse of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation) to imply that if the domain were expanded it would be discontinuous despite zero not being in it's domain. Domains in particular are commonly abused this way.

Answer (score 1):

Calculus books and mathematicians tend to disagree on exactly this point.

Answer (score 0):

In general if we have a continuous function $f$ defined on some open interval $(a,b)$ we could hope to extend $f$ to a continuous function on [a,b]. For example, f(x)=x^2 on (0,1) can be extended with no problems to [0,1].
We always need to consider the behavior on the boundary of the domain of our function.

In your case what happens if you consider the limit for $x \to 0$?